# Checking filesize and its distribution in HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Is it possible to know filesize in blocks and its distribution over DataNodes in Hadoop?

```
Currently I am using: 
frolo@A11:~/hadoop> $HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop dfs -stat "%b %o %r %n" /user/frolo/input/rmat-*
318339 67108864 1 rmat-10.0
392835957 67108864 1 rmat-20.0
```

Which does not show actual number of blocks created after uploading file to HDFS. And I dont know any way how to find out its distribution.

Thanks,
   Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `%r` in your stat command shows the replication factor of the queried file. If this is 1, it means there will only be only a single replica across the cluster for blocks belonging to this file. The `hadoop fs -ls` output also shows this value for listed files as one of its numeric columns, as replication factor is a per file FS attribute.

If you are looking to find where the blocks reside instead, you are looking for `hdfs fsck` (or `hadoop fsck` if using a dated release) instead. The below, for example, will let you see the list of block IDs and their respective set of resident locations, for any file:

`hdfs fsck /user/frolo/input/rmat-10.0 -files -blocks -locations`

Comment: Thank you very much, it the thing I needed.BTW, may be you could help me with another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21622484/hdfs-file-is-not-distributed-after-upload ;-)