# HDFS: file is not distributed after upload

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I've deployed hadoop (0.20.203.0rc1) on 8-node cluster. After uploading file onto hdfs I've got this file only on one of the nodes instead of being uniformly distributed across all nodes. What can be the issue?

```
$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop dfs -copyFromLocal ../data/rmat-20.0 /user/frolo/input/rmat-20.0

$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop dfs -stat "%b %o %r %n" /user/frolo/input/rmat-*
1220222968 67108864 1 rmat-20.0

$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop dfsadmin -report 
Configured Capacity: 2536563998720 (2.31 TB)
Present Capacity: 1642543419392 (1.49 TB)
DFS Remaining: 1641312030720 (1.49 TB)
DFS Used: 1231388672 (1.15 GB)
DFS Used%: 0.07%
Under replicated blocks: 0
Blocks with corrupt replicas: 0
Missing blocks: 0

-------------------------------------------------
Datanodes available: 8 (8 total, 0 dead)

Name: 10.10.1.15:50010
Decommission Status : Normal
Configured Capacity: 317070499840 (295.29 GB)
DFS Used: 24576 (24 KB)
Non DFS Used: 131536928768 (122.5 GB)
DFS Remaining: 185533546496(172.79 GB)
DFS Used%: 0%
DFS Remaining%: 58.51%
Last contact: Fri Feb 07 12:10:27 MSK 2014


Name: 10.10.1.13:50010
Decommission Status : Normal
Configured Capacity: 317070499840 (295.29 GB)
DFS Used: 24576 (24 KB)
Non DFS Used: 131533377536 (122.5 GB)
DFS Remaining: 185537097728(172.79 GB)
DFS Used%: 0%
DFS Remaining%: 58.52%
Last contact: Fri Feb 07 12:10:27 MSK 2014


Name: 10.10.1.17:50010
Decommission Status : Normal
Configured Capacity: 317070499840 (295.29 GB)
DFS Used: 24576 (24 KB)
Non DFS Used: 120023924736 (111.78 GB)
DFS Remaining: 197046550528(183.51 GB)
DFS Used%: 0%
DFS Remaining%: 62.15%
Last contact: Fri Feb 07 12:10:27 MSK 2014


Name: 10.10.1.18:50010
Decommission Status : Normal
Configured Capacity: 317070499840 (295.29 GB)
DFS Used: 24576 (24 KB)
Non DFS Used: 78510628864 (73.12 GB)
DFS Remaining: 238559846400(222.18 GB)
DFS Used%: 0%
DFS Remaining%: 75.24%
Last contact: Fri Feb 07 12:10:24 MSK 2014


Name: 10.10.1.14:50010
Decommission Status : Normal
Configured Capacity: 317070499840 (295.29 GB)
DFS Used: 24576 (24 KB)
Non DFS Used: 131537530880 (122.5 GB)
DFS Remaining: 185532944384(172.79 GB)
DFS Used%: 0%
DFS Remaining%: 58.51%
Last contact: Fri Feb 07 12:10:27 MSK 2014


Name: 10.10.1.11:50010
Decommission Status : Normal
Configured Capacity: 317070499840 (295.29 GB)
DFS Used: 1231216640 (1.15 GB)
Non DFS Used: 84698116096 (78.88 GB)
DFS Remaining: 231141167104(215.27 GB)
DFS Used%: 0.39%
DFS Remaining%: 72.9%
Last contact: Fri Feb 07 12:10:24 MSK 2014


Name: 10.10.1.16:50010
Decommission Status : Normal
Configured Capacity: 317070499840 (295.29 GB)
DFS Used: 24576 (24 KB)
Non DFS Used: 131537494016 (122.5 GB)
DFS Remaining: 185532981248(172.79 GB)
DFS Used%: 0%
DFS Remaining%: 58.51%
Last contact: Fri Feb 07 12:10:27 MSK 2014


Name: 10.10.1.12:50010
Decommission Status : Normal
Configured Capacity: 317070499840 (295.29 GB)
DFS Used: 24576 (24 KB)
Non DFS Used: 84642578432 (78.83 GB)
DFS Remaining: 232427896832(216.47 GB)
DFS Used%: 0%
DFS Remaining%: 73.3%
Last contact: Fri Feb 07 12:10:27 MSK 2014
```

Comment: I have just uploaded another file using the same command: $HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop dfs -copyFromLocal ../data/rmat-20.0 /user/frolo/input/rmat-20.0-2  and it also have been loaded to the 10.10.1.11 node, which by the way is a node where I run commands (master node).

Comment: what is your replication factor? HDFS data might not always be be placed uniformly across the DataNode. If your primary concern is all data on single node and if you are looking for ways to force balancing data across nodes (with replication at whatever value) a simple option is $HADOOP_HOME/bin/start-balancer.sh which will run a balancing process to move blocks around the cluster automatically

Answer (score 1):

Your file has been written with a *replication factor* of `1`, as evidenced by your `hadoop fs -stat` command output. This means only one block replica will exist for the blocks under the file.

The default *replication factor* for writes is governed by the property `dfs.replication` under `$HADOOP_HOME/conf/hdfs-site.xml`. If unspecified under it, the default is `3`, but its likely that you have an override of it specified whose value is `1`. Changing its value back to `3` or removing it altogether (to invoke default) will make all new file writes use `3` replicas by default.

You may also pass a specific *replication factor* with each write command using the `-D` property passing method supported by the `hadoop fs` utility, such as:

`hadoop fs -Ddfs.replication=3 -copyFromLocal ../data/rmat-20.0 /user/frolo/input/rmat-20.0`

And you may alter an existing file's *replication factor* by using the `hadoop fs -setrep` utility, such as:

`hadoop fs -setrep 3 -w /user/frolo/input/rmat-20.0`

Files with a `HDFS` *replication factor* greater than `1` will show up automatically distributed across multiple nodes. `HDFS` will never write more than one replica of a block onto the same `DataNode`.